# Focus out control in blazor(show/hide <ul> inside <li>) without javascript

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I am going to create a DropDown and a DropDownMenu. When DropDown  button clicked, DropDownMenu must be shown.
If user click outside of each DropDown or DropDownMenu, DropDownMenu must close.
Also, if user click on any item in DropDownMenu, it must redirect to url.
I create a component, but it not works properly. DropDownMenu not closed when lost focus.

Here is my complete component code:

Main navigation:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                @Items
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Items { get; set; }
}
```

Menu item:

```
@if (Items != null)
{
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" @onclick="Toggle" @onblur="Close">
        <a class="nav-link @(Disabled?"disabled":"")" role="button">
            @Text
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu @(isVisible?"d-block":"d-none")" @onclick="Close">
            @Items
        </ul>
    </li>
}
else
{
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link @(Disabled?"disabled":"")" aria-current="page" href="@NavigateUrl">@Text</a>
    </li>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Items { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; } = "Menu Item";
    [Parameter] public string NavigateUrl { get; set; } = "#";
    [Parameter] public bool Disabled { get; set; } = false;  
    private bool isVisible = false;

    public void Toggle()
    {
        isVisible = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        //await Task.Delay(200);
        isVisible = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
}
```

usage:

```
 <MLMenu>
            <Items>
                <MLMenuItem Text="Home" NavigateUrl="/" />
                <MLMenuItem Text="Link" NavigateUrl="Counter" />
                <MLMenuItem Text="DropDown" >
                    <Items>
                        <MLMenuItem Text="Counter" NavigateUrl="counter" />
                        <MLMenuItem Text="Fetch Data" NavigateUrl="fetchdata" />
                    </Items>
                </MLMenuItem>
                <MLMenuItem Text="DropDown">
                    <Items>
                        <MLMenuItem Text="Counter" NavigateUrl="counter" />
                        <MLMenuItem Text="Fetch Data" NavigateUrl="fetchdata" />
                    </Items>
                </MLMenuItem>
                <MLMenuItem Text="Disabled" Disabled=true />
            </Items>
        </MLMenu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`li` is not a focusable html element by default so you have to set `tabindex="-1"` to make the element focusable but not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation (`Tab` key). Try:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" @onclick="Toggle" tabindex="-1" @onblur="Close">
    ...   
</li>
```

Comment: You can use `tabindex=-1` if you don't want the element to be in the tab order.  It's common to use it on say divs to give them focusable behaviour.

Comment: Yeah `tabindex="-1"` is more suitable for this scenario thanks.